# I am not sure why I am getting output for this?

Tags: c++

I was learning some string handling in C++ and was doing hit and trail on a code and surprisingly got output for the given code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char str[12]={'\67','a','v','i'};
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
```

**Surprisingly I get 7avi printed .**

But if I replace '\67' with '\68'. The following error is shown on Repl.it (https://repl.it/languages/cpp)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[12]={'\68','a','v','i'};
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}



main.cpp:6:19: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    char str[12]={'\68','a','v','i'};
                  ^
main.cpp:6:19: error: constant expression evaluates to 1592 which cannot
      be narrowed to type 'char' [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    char str[12]={'\68','a','v','i'};
                  ^~~~~
main.cpp:6:19: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
    char str[12]={'\68','a','v','i'};
                  ^~~~~
                  static_cast<char>( )
main.cpp:6:19: warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes
      value from 1592 to 56 [-Wconstant-conversion]
    char str[12]={'\68','a','v','i'};
                 ~^~~~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
compiler exit status 1
```

Please someone explain this behavior.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 5):

The `\nnn` notation, where nnn are digits between 0 and 7, is for octal (base 8) notation.  So in `\68`, 68 is not a valid octal number.  The number one more than 67 is 70.  The way it's interpreting the code is that you have '\6' as character 6 in octal, but then an additional `'8'` ASCII character inside your character literal - hence a multi-character constant, which can not be stored in a `char` variable.  You could store it in a "wide character":

```
wchar_t str[12]={'\68','a','v','i'};
```

But, there is no `operator<<` overload to display an array of `wchar_t`, so your `cout << str` line will match the `void*` overload and just display the memory address of the first element in the array, rather than any of the characters themselves.

You can fix that using:

```
wcout << str;
```

Separately, I recommend putting a newline after your output too.  Without it, your output may be overwritten by the console prompt before you can see it, though that doesn't happen in the online REPL you're using.  It should look like:

```
wcout << str << '\n';
```

Comment: I doubt the OP actually wants wide characters. They just wanted ASCII #67 to appear instead. That's obviously me reading into it, though.

Comment: @Chipster: yeah - OP said he was just learning by trial and error, so while I'm also sure he had no intention of using wide characters, serendipity has brought them to his attention....

Comment: @TonyDelroy Thank you so much Sir. Now I get an insight of what  was happening actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to type in an ASCII character using either octal or hex.(octal usually begins with a `0`, but hex with a `0x`). Just don't put the the ASCII code in quotes, instead put the code straight into the array, like so:

```
char str[12] = {68, 'a', 'v', 'i'}; //decimal 
char str[12] = {0x44, 'a', 'v', 'i'}; //hex  
char str[12] = {0104, 'a', 'v', 'i'}; //octal
```

### Side Note

Please don't use `<bits/stdc++.h>`. It's not standardized(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h/31816096#31816096), for a more detailed explanation.) Instead include `<iostream>` for `cout` and the other requisite libraries for your other needs.

Comment: Yeah I was kinda trying it in that sense only . Thanks for clarifying .